# How to view data from two different tables with room, mvvm?

Tags: android, android-mvvm

I have attempted to save my User and Eval data. But, when I switch to my fragment to have the complete list of my 2 tables. Nothing is displayed. I can't find the solution. Thank you for your help

Here, my code on EvalFragment:

```
fun saveDatainRoomDb() {
         val idUser = args.currentUser.id
        val first_name =args.currentUser.firstName
        val last_name = args.currentUser.lastName
        val numeroTerrain = args.currentUser.nbTeam
        val note_finale_classement = view?.noteClassement?.text.toString().trim()
        val note_finale_strategie = view?.noteVolume?.text.toString().trim()
        val note_finale_mobilite = view?.noteDeplacement?.text.toString().trim()
        val note_finale_afl_2 = view?.noteAFL2?.text.toString().trim()
        val note_finale_afl_3 = view?.noteAFL3?.text.toString().trim()
        val note_finale_sur_vingt = view?.note_sur_vingt?.text.toString().trim()
        val userDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext())?.userDao()
        val userEntity = User(idUser, first_name, last_name, numeroTerrain)
          if(userDao != null) userDao?.addUser(userEntity)

        val evalEntity = Eval(idUser, note_finale_classement, note_finale_strategie, note_finale_mobilite, note_finale_afl_2, note_finale_afl_3, note_finale_sur_vingt)
        // Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"" + evalEntity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        evalDao?.addEval(evalEntity)

        //Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Ajout avec succès !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Here, my code of my ListEvaFragment:

```
class ListEvalFragment : Fragment() {

    //Pour accéder au fab
    private var _binding: FragmentListEvalBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentListEvalBinding.inflate(inflater, container,false)
        val view = binding.root

        //Recyclerview pour affichier le custom row et les données
        val adapter = ListEvalAdapter()
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        // UserViewModel pour afficher les données
        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)

        mUserViewModel.readAllDataEval?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { userWithEval ->
            adapter.setData(userWithEval)

        })

        /*
        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener{
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_addFragment)
        }

        binding.floatingActiontTri.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_listCsvFragment)
        }

         */

        // Add menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.menu_delete){
            deleteAllUsers()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun deleteAllUsers() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes"){ _, _ ->
            mUserViewModel.deleteAllUsers()
            Toast.makeText(
                requireContext(),
                "Suppression complète réussie",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        builder.setNegativeButton("No"){_, _ -> }
        builder.setTitle("Tout Supprimer?")
        builder.setMessage("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer l'ensemble des données?")
        builder.create().show()
    }
}
```

Here, my code of my ListEvalAdapter:

```
class ListEvalAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ListEvalAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    var userWithEvalList = emptyList<UserWithEval>()

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_note, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userWithEvalList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = userWithEvalList[position]

        holder.itemView.id_txt.text = currentItem.id
        holder.itemView.firstName_txt.text = currentItem.firstName
        holder.itemView.lastName_txt.text = currentItem.lastName
        holder.itemView.note_strategie_txt.text = currentItem.note_strategie
        holder.itemView.note_mobilite_txt.text = currentItem.note_mobilite
        holder.itemView.note_classement_txt.text = currentItem.note_classement
        holder.itemView.note_afl2_txt.text = currentItem.note_afl2
        holder.itemView.note_afl3_txt.text = currentItem.note_afl3
        holder.itemView.note_finale_txt.text = currentItem.note_sur_vingt


        holder.itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.rowLayoutNote).setOnClickListener {
            //TODO
        }
    }

    fun setData(userWithEval: List<UserWithEval>) {
        this.userWithEvalList = userWithEval
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Here, my code of UserDao:

```
@Dao
```

interface UserDao {

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table ORDER BY id ASC")
fun getUserData(): LiveData<List<User>>?

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun addUser(user: User)

@Update
fun insertEval(eval: Eval)

@Update
suspend fun updateUser(user: User)

@Delete
suspend fun deleteUser(user: User)

@Query("DELETE FROM user_table")
suspend fun deleteAllUsers()

@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table JOIN eval_table  on user_table.id = eval_table.idEval ")
fun getAllUserWithEval(): LiveData<List<UserWithEval>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id=:id")
fun getOneUser(id: Int) : User
```

}

here, my code of EvalDao:

```
@Dao
```

interface EvalDao {

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM eval_table ORDER BY idEval ASC")
fun getEvalData(): LiveData<List<Eval>>?

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun addEval(eval: Eval)

@Update
fun insertEval(eval: Eval)

@Update
suspend fun updateEval(eval: Eval)

@Delete
suspend fun deleteEval(eval: Eval)

@Query("DELETE FROM eval_table")
suspend fun deleteAllEvals()
```

}

Here, my code of UserDatabase

@Database(entities = [User::class, Eval::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class UserDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

```
abstract fun userDao(): UserDao?
abstract fun evalDao(): EvalDao?

companion object{
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE : UserDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): UserDatabase?{
        val tempInstance = INSTANCE
        if (tempInstance != null){
            return  tempInstance
        }
        synchronized(this){
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                UserDatabase::class.java,
                "user_database"
            )
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            return instance
        }
    }
}
```

}

here, my UserViewModel, my function getAllUserWithEval is never used:

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application) {

val readAllData: LiveData<List<User>>?
val readAllDataEval: LiveData<List<UserWithEval>>? = null
private val repository: UserRepository


init {
    val userDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application)?.userDao()
    repository = UserRepository(userDao!!)
    readAllData = repository.readAllData
}

fun addUser(user: User) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.addUser(user)
    }
}

fun updateUser(user: User) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.updateUser(user)
    }
}

fun deleteUser(user: User) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.deleteUser(user)
    }
}

fun deleteAllUsers() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.deleteAllUsers()
    }
}

fun getAllUserWithEval(userWithEval: LiveData<List<UserWithEval>>?)  {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.getAllUserWithEval(userWithEval)
    }
}
```

}

Here, my UserRepository:

```
class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {

val readAllData: LiveData<List<User>>? = userDao.getUserData()

suspend fun addUser(user: User){
    userDao.addUser(user)
}

suspend fun updateUser(user: User){
    userDao.updateUser(user)
}

suspend fun deleteUser(user: User){
    userDao.deleteUser(user)
}

suspend fun deleteAllUsers(){
    userDao.deleteAllUsers()
}

fun getAllUserWithEval(userWithEval: LiveData<List<UserWithEval>>?) {
    userDao.getAllUserWithEval()
}
```

}

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: check  database is not EMPTY

Comment: I have forgotten to put @Insert addEval(eval: Eval). Now, i take my user table and eval table are ok... But, i don't arrive to show the data of my two tables (user and eval)

Comment: I did not get it. u mean u want to get data of 2 tables and show them right?

Comment: here mUserViewModel.readAllDataEval?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { userWithEval ->
            adapter.setData(userWithEval)
   log it to see if it is arrining data correctly
        })

Comment: Yes, i want to get data of 2 tables and show them on the same line.. the log is empty

Comment: first go and search for sql join

Comment: Log show "2018-01-03 21:36:40.771 11005-11005/fr.epsfenelonlille.evaluationvolley E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno""

Comment: I fix my problem. Only is the name of my function setData. I change this name because it's a redundant name

Comment: oh, thanks god, i am happy to hear that

Comment: but wait, did u try to fix it for 10 days?

Comment: I'm not a professional developer. It's only my hobby  i don't have many times to coding

Comment: OK, now I got it, hope u best. so it is your second job

Comment: I strongly suggest you after finishg your project, go and learn FLUTTER